# Is there exists a set which contains as elements all its finite subsets?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is there exists a set $A$ such that if $F$ is a finite subset of A, then $F\in A$?  Under ZFC axiom system. 
I guess the answer may not, but I’m not sure yet.
Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your question's title and your actual question seem to be different. In your question you ask whether there exists a set $\;A\;$ which contains *as elements* all its finite subsets. That's different from what is written in the title, so: which one do you want and what have you done so far about that?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, Antonio, I mean it contains as elements all its finite subsets. I edit title right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are such sets, an example is $V_\omega$, the set of all sets which are hereditarily finite, meaning that $x\in V_\omega$ if and only if $x$ is finite, all elements of $x$ are finite, all elements of all elements of $x$ are finite, and so on.

If $y\subseteq V_\omega$ is finite, this means that for every $x\in y$ we have $x\in V_\omega$, that is elements of $y$ are hereditarily finite sets. Since $y$ is finite this means that $y$ itself is an hereditarily finite set, hence $y\in V_\omega$.

More generally let $\mathcal P_{\mathrm{fin}}(X)$ denote the set of all finite subsets of $X$ and let $\mathcal P^n_{\mathrm{fin}}(X)=\mathcal P_{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathcal P^{n-1}_{\mathrm{fin}}(X))$, where $\mathcal P^0_{\mathrm{fin}}(X)=X$ by convention. Then $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathcal P^n_{\mathrm{fin}}(X)$ is a set with the desired property regardless of $X$.

Comment: Thanks, Codenotti. By the last paragraph, if we replace “finite subsets” with “subsets whose cardinal are $\kappa$, the same claim is also true. Am I right?

Comment: This construction looks like it's the Kleene star operation on some monoid. I can't quite pin down what that monoid would be, though.